# URL schema for Microsoft Outlook Android

Tags: android, outlook

I want to open Microsoft Outlook from my custom mobile app . I am not able to find the URL schema for it .

Answer (score 1):

Try using `ms-outlook://` to open outlook on andorid.

You can use something like `ms-outlook://example@example.com`. (not sure about it.)

To open the app you can use package name `com.microsoft.office.outlook`